# How to run a Visual Studio solution without having to add the included files show in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a solution called IncludeFileHelp which uses SampleClass.h and SampleClass2.cpp.

```
#include <SampleClass2.h>

void main() {
    SampleClass2 sampleClass2Obj;
    sampleClass2Obj.printHello();
}
```

SampleClass.h

```
#pragma
#include <iostream>

class SampleClass2 {
public:
    SampleClass2() {}
    void printHello();
};
```

SampleClass2.cpp

```
#include <SampleClass2.h>

void SampleClass2::printHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello from SampleClass2!" << std::endl;
}
```

I added to correct directory path of SampleClass2.h and SampleClass.cpp to the Additional Include Directories.

When I add SampleClass2.h to the Header Files in Solution Explorer and add SampleClass2.cpp to the Source Files in Solution Explorer, the program runs without any problems.

However, if I remove SampleClass2.h and SampleClass2.cpp from the Solution Explorer I get this error:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SampleClass2::printHello(void)" (?printHello@SampleClass2@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

The only way I know how to resolve this error is to drag and drop the SampleClass2.h and SampleClass2.cpp files back to the Solution Explorer. This becomes a tedious problem when copying or cloning the solution, as I have to manually add all the included files even though Visual Studio recognizes the class and it's functions.

What I can do so that my program can run in Visual Studio 2019 without having to have the included class header files and .cpp files in Solution Explorer?

The only thing I can think of is changing #pragma to:

```
#ifndef SAMPLECLASS2
#define SAMPLECLASS2

...

#endif /*SAMPLECLASS2*/
```

but that does not work.

---

[Images of my Visual Studio Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Ja7.png)

Comment: The header isn't the problem; compilation worked. Your error is an undefined reference because `SampleClass2.cpp` isn't included in your project. It needs to be. Period. And before you attempt to circumvent that scenario by `#include`-ing a .cpp file into another.. just.. .don't.

Comment: Ok, it can run without the header files in the Solution Explorer. But, do I need to have SampleClass2.cpp in the Solution Explorer? I ask because other libraries, such as OpenCV, does not require me to have the .cpp files shown in the Solution Explorer. My SampleClass2.cpp is in the same folder as SampleClass2.h.

Comment: *"I ask because other libraries"* - yeah, that's the point; they're *libraries* already built and linked to your program. You don't have that with your sample cpp. You can make one, of course, but that's somewhat beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: So if I want to run my code without having my class .cpp files in the Solution Explorer, I would need to learn how to make .dll and .lib files for my classes?

Comment: A library, static or dynamic, would be on the agenda, yes. The distribution of that would be a public header, a .lib, and in the case of dynamic library (dll), that too. The lib is linked to your program in the additional link dependencies, and if dynamic, the dll must be resolvable at runtime; usually placed in the same folder as your executable. As I said, setting that all up is well outside the reaches of this post, and should be investigated by you. there are probably plenty of web links that can instruct you how to build whatever kind of library you prefer using VS.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method is to create a lib or dll. Then link the lib or dll to the project to meet your needs. You could refer the following Microsoft Documents for more information.

1. [Walkthrough: Create and use a static library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160)
2. [Walkthrough: Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @CoolGuy Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.